# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: ios7, swift, xcode6, cfnetwork, nshttpurlresponse

I wrote a Swift App with Xcode6 Beta 2 that does some networking using CFNetwork classes such as `NSURLRequest` and `NSHTTPURLResponse`.

The App works just fine with iOS 8, still, when I try to run it on an iOS 7 device or in the simulator running iOS 7, I get the following error when starting the App:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPURLResponse
  Referenced from: /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0A61F43-A67C-4803-8F5D-77C3972107BE/data/Applications/E0C7C89F-9EEE-4893-BE5B-FCC224F2855D/CheckYourWeather.app/CheckYourWeather
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
 in /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0A61F43-A67C-4803-8F5D-77C3972107BE/data/Applications/E0C7C89F-9EEE-4893-BE5B-FCC224F2855D/CheckYourWeather.app/CheckYourWeather
```

I've done some research and found out that it's a linking problem. Still, I know that the classes I'm using are already available in iOS 7.

I also tried to add the `CFNetwork.framework` to the frameworks in the project settings and set it to optional, which only caused the App to crash during runtime.

The confusing part for me is: I wrote a Test App and just pasted my code I used in the main app into it and it worked just fine. Therefore the code is probably not the problem.

Deleting the App from the Simulator/Device, make a clean on the project and deleting Xcode's DerivedData haven't solved the problem.

**Update:**

Here's the code that causes the crash:

```
extension NSURLRequest {
    class func plainPostRequest(url: NSURL, httpBody: String) -> NSURLRequest {
        let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.HTTPBody = httpBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        urlRequest.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

But that's just an example. Any use of CFNetwork classes causes the App to crash during start.

Comment: Show the code that causes this error.

Comment: I edited the post to include the code.

Comment: Try add CFNetwork.framework to Embedded Binaries in Target > General.

Comment: I added it – didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post more crash log? Also did you try symbolicate crash? May get some information there.

Comment: I just added the remaining crash log. How do I symbolicate a crash and what for?

Comment: Is the app crashes on iOS 8 simulator? (Also I wouldn't set the framework to Optional, it's not a solution)

Comment: It works fine in iOS 8 Simulator but crashes on iOS 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a known bug with the iOS 8 SDK. As a workaround, move Foundation.framework *before* CFNetwork.framework in the list of frameworks to link to in the project settings.

Comment: Didn't help. Maybe any other suggestion? (

Answer (score 2):

For me just moving the Foundation.framework before CFNetwork.framework doesn't work. I need to close and reopen the project for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by creating a new project and copying all my classes and assets there. Unfortunately I couldn't find out what the actual source of the problem was.

Any alternative solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would blame it on beta software (Xcode) combined with beta-language (Swift) :) .

Answer (score 0):

Moving Foundation.framework would not help so after further investigation the further method helped me.

I was able to resolve the problem by adding main.m file at Build Phases -> Compile Sources

Apparently it couldn't find the main.m file.